# Casting int to void* loses precision, and what is the solution in required cases

Tags: c++, pthreads

I know the reason of such error. "int" is not large enough to hold bytes of "void *". But my question is that how should I then handle `pthread_create` of Linux, when I want to pass a function's argument for it to be executed. In many examples, I see such function forward-declaration:

```
void* thread_proc(void* arg);
```

And then in the function, a file-pointer is passed as `arg` (which is of type int). But the compiler (logically) throws an error which warns against the casting of int to void. I even have used the intptr_t (aka long pointer) but to no avail.

```
result = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_proc, (void *)new_request_socket);
```

`new_request_socket` is an int representing the fd of a socket.

How the I can pass an integer as an argument of a function is itself passed as function to be executed by `pthread_create()`.

Comment: You don't need to handle `pthread_create`. You simply use `std::thread`. Problem solved.

Comment: Pass a pointer to the `int` rather than the `int` value directly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: What is there to elaborate? What part of "use `std::thread` and avoid the whole problem" is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably passing int itself not pointer to the int.

You should actually pass pointer

```
result = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, thread_proc, (void *)&new_request_socket);
```

And in `thread_proc(void *arg)` use it as such:

```
void thread_proc(void *arg)
{
    int  new_request_socket = *arg; //please put appropriate cast
}
```

EDIT: To clarify what Sam and Lightness points about passing the pointer `thread_proc`:

- Dont pass pointer to the local variable i.e. new_request_socket should be allocated on heap using malloc
- simultaneous access to `new_request_socket` should be streamlined using locks
- Dont free `new_request_socket` until `thread_proc` reads it.

Essentially making `new_request_socket` a pointer you will have to write more code. So dont write more code and use `std::thread` :)

Comment: This is unlikely to be safe, unless you make further modifications.

Comment: The problem with this approach is the need for `new_request_socket` to remain in scope until the new thread reads it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes but thats the limitation of `pthread_create` that it accepts pointer, so your program must be designed to handle those cases.

Comment: Yes, but it should be designed to handle them correctly. Of course, there hasn't been a good reason (in general) to use this archaic C-like nonsense since the early 2000s. `boost::thread` and now `std::thread` plzkthx.